# Find text then add line after in Python

Tags: python, plist

I need to read a plist file and search for a string, then add a new line of text on the next line. I can't imagine it will take much to do this. However the plist is in binary format so not exactly sure how to deal with that.

Thanks in advance,

Aaron

```
#Convert plist to XML
os.system('plutil -convert xml1 com.apple.iChat.Jabber.plist')

AutoDiscovery = "<integer>0<integer>"

import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("com.apple.iChat.Jabber.plist",inplace=1):
   line = line.replace("<key>AutoDiscoverHostAndPort</key>",AutoDiscovery)
   print line,

#Concert plist to binary file
os.system('plutil -convert binary1 com.apple.iChat.Jabber.plist')
```

Comment: Use `plutil` to convert.

Answer (score 2):

You want to convert it into xml format first:

```
plutil -convert xml file.plist
```

Then the rest should be fairly easy.

EDIT:

```
newFile = open('file.copy', 'w+')
for line in open('file'):
    if (line.find('string_to_find') >= 0):
        # do something with "line"
    newFile.write(line)
newFile.close()
```

EDIT2:

```
# convert plist from binary to xml

plist = plistlib.readPlist('your.plist')
plist['key'] = 0
plistlib.writePlist('your.plist')

# convert plist from xml to binary
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figured this out to convert to xml and back. I'm not sure however how to find the string of text and add a new line of text  after. Are you familiar with this?

Comment: Sorry I'm not the best with python. I assume I need to write something under the if statement but not sure how to make it write after the string that is found. Specifically, i just need to write <integer>1</integer> after the 'string_to_find'

Comment: You could try a bit harder to find out the solution yourself: http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR25/PQR2.5.html

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. So far this is what I have (see above). Is there a way to use the replace so that it replaces the line below what I'm asking it to find?

Comment: With your current approach, you could simply use a flag: e.g. set lineFound = true, and catch the flag on the next line. But it is probably more elegant to use plistlib after you have converted the plist to xml. E.g. (see above)

Comment: How would I catch the flag on next line? I guess I'm just not so certain on how to edit the following line once I've found "<key>AutoDiscoverHostAndPort</key>" in this case.

Comment: You may need to read about "flag-controlled loops": http://www.ada95.ch/doc/tut1/Loops/control.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [`plistlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/plistlib.html) for all your plist file needs. No conversion needed.

Comment: Does plistlib support binary plists?

Comment: I figured out how to use plutil to convert to xml and the back to binary. What I'm still having troubles with is, finding a string in the file and adding a new line of text on the following line.